# NextJS: Unexpected token '?'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, next.js

I have a freshly installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS on which I have installed npm and docker.

When I want to start my NextJS web server (`npm run dev`) and the following error message appears:

```js
niklas@srv-code01:~/Desktop/Code/Javascript/NextJS/website_01$ npm run dev

> website_01@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

/home/niklas/Desktop/Code/Javascript/NextJS/website_01/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-dev.js:315
            showAll: args["--show-all"] ?? false,
                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.dev (/home/niklas/Desktop/Code/Javascript/NextJS/website_01/node_modules/next/dist/lib/commands.js:10:30)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/niklas/Desktop/Code/Javascript/NextJS/website_01/node_modules/next/dist/bin/next:141:28)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
```

I can't see anything from the error message. What is the reason for the error? The error message also occurs with the following command: `npm run start`

I have the latest version of NPM installed.

Start of the NPM Development or Production Server on Port 3000

Comment: What version of node are you running?

Comment: Version: v12.22.9

Comment: Nullish coalescing isn't in node until 14 I think see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_coalescing#browser_compatibility).

Comment: https://node.green/#ES2020-features--nullish-coalescing-operator-----

Comment: I solved the problem by updating NPM like this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/426750/how-can-i-update-my-nodejs-to-the-latest-version#answer-480642

Answer (score 50, accepted):

I had the same error and to resolve that I used the **node version manager(nvm)** to update my node.js version to **18.12.1**.

To fix this, you need to follow the steps in this order-

1. Run this command to get the **nvm**.
   `curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.39.1/install.sh | bash`
2. Restart your terminal.
3. Install nvm- `nvm install v18.12.1`
4. Start nvm- `npm run dev`

You can use `nvm list-remote` to look at a complete list of the versions to choose from.

For more information, read here under option 3-
[installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager](https://digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-ubuntu-22-04#option-3-installing-node-using-the-node-version-manager)

Comment: Just wanted to add here that if you restart your project, you'll just have to remember to run nvm use 18.12.1

Answer (score -3):

You can try init project by `npx create-next-app@latest`, not `npx create-next-app`. It works for me. Good luck~