# SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?' Problem for run my next application while deploying to Google App engine

Tags: google-app-engine, next.js

I am trying to deploy a next application to Google App Engine, the next build is working fine locally but when I am tring to deploy to Google App Engine I am getting the following error

```
Step #2: SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
Step #2:     at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:931:16)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:979:27)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
Step #2:     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:879:32)
Step #2:     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:724:14)
Step #2:     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:903:19)
Step #2:     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
Step #2:     at Object.<anonymous> (/app/node_modules/next/dist/cli/next-build.js:10:37)
Step #2:     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1015:30)
Step #2:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1035:10)
Step #2: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
Step #2: npm ERR! errno 1
```

Please help

Comment: What is the node version you are using? Can you try upgrading? Also share your `json` file if possible. Have a look at this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74865526/18265570) once

Comment: We are using the Next version 13.1.4.
I have checked with the lower version, the deployment is working.

Comment: Glad to hear that downgrading the `next` version solve the issue. I'll recommend you to report the same issue [here](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues)